# Printing html links/anchors in Matlab command window to files with spaces in path

Tags: matlab, anchor, whitespace, filepath

### The problem

When I run the following line in Matlab

```
sprintf('<a href="matlab:system(''start %s'');">%s</a>', url, text)
```

I get a clickable link in the Matlab command window. Which I use to allow the user to easily open: .png, .pdf or .html files on Windows

The problem start when the url contains whitespaces? Yes some of the users of the software likes to use spaces in paths...

### What I Have Tried

None of the examples in the following script is working...

```
url = 'C:\Temp\path with space\test.htm';
text = 'test.htm'

disp(sprintf('<a href="matlab:system(''start %s'');">%s</a>', url, text));
disp(sprintf('<a href="matlab:system(''start "%s"'');">%s</a>', url, text));
disp(sprintf('<a href="matlab:system(''start &quot;%s&quot;'');">%s</a>', url, text));
disp(sprintf('<a href="matlab:system([''start '' char(34) ''%s'' char(34)]);">%s</a>', url, text));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution seems to be skipping the 'start' part:

```
disp(sprintf('<a href="matlab:system(''%s'');">%s</a>', url, text));
```